# I am getting warning "Empty Bibliography" using bibtex at backend. It's been 2 days I am unable to resolve this problem

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I tried to compile latex 2 time after bibtex compilation. My references are in bib file and I am using jabref.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[backend = bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}


\addbibresource{facial expression recognition.bib}
\begin{document}

\title{}

\cite{Ekman1971}


\maketitle

%\begin{abstract}
%This document is a model and instructions for \LaTeX.
%This and the IEEEtran.cls file define the components of your paper [title, text, heads, etc.]. *CRITICAL: Do Not Use Symbols, Special Characters, Footnotes, 
%or Math in Paper Title or Abstract.
%\end{abstract}

%\begin{IEEEkeywords}
%component, formatting, style, styling, insert
%\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}



\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't use spaces in files names (like in your bib file). If this doesn't solve the problem show the content of the blg-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed. No effect.

Comment: The do what I said in my second sentence.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: Facial Expression Recognition.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
White space in argument---line 3 of file Facial Expression Recognition.aux
 : \bibdata{Facial_Expression_Recognition-blx,facial
 :                                                   expression recognition}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: Facial_Expression_Recognition-blx.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Ekman1971"
Biblatex version: 3.8
(There was 1 error message)"

Comment: well obviously there are still some spaces in file names around, as one can see in `Facial Expression Recognition.aux`

Comment: The `.blg` file still complains about a file name with spaces in it (`Facial Expression Recognition`). Make sure that no file name involved has spaces in it (your `.bib` file *and* your `.tex` file) and that you have renamed all instances of the file correctly. Then remove the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, `-blx.bib`) and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh thank you so much. Yes, I removed spaces in all other files. Now It's okay!!!! Now there is only one warning left "Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable." Can you tell me about it?

Comment: well you are using `backend = bibtex,`, and bibtex is much less powerfull than biber. If you want to switch: remove this text and setup your editor to call biber instead of bibtex. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Answer (score 0):

I was getting warning because I had white spaces in my other files. I removed white spaces and now it's all working.